# can i pass mongodb query as a string in php

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I am planning to run mongodb query from php platform text area as picture below where I want to write query like

```
 array('Chat_time' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end))
```

[image]

and execute like

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->Forensic;
$coll= $db->mobile_
$user_code = $coll->find($_POST['txt_area']));
```

but cannot execute becuause I think when I convert query to string it cannot understand => as a command.

what would be the best way pass this command as a string and php will understand.

Answer (score 0):

you should write json to your text area. like:

```
{
    "Chat_time": {
        "$gt" => "xxx",
        "$lte" => "yyy"
    }
}
```

in php

```
// json string to array using json_decode
$query = json_decode($_POST['txt_area'], true);
$user_code = $coll->find($query);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but not really getting any answer. following error message comes Notice: Undefined variable: p in C:\xampp\htdocs\reports3.php on line 157

Warning: MongoCollection::find(): expects parameter 1 to be an array or object, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\reports3.php on line 159